# pandas.DataFrame.where alignment

Tags: python, pandas

I was studying pandas indexing and selection and came across function `pandas.DataFrame.where()`. This function has got `axis` and `level` for alignment purpose. 
For example:

```
In [21]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(8,4), index = pd.date_range('20000101',periods=8), columns = list('ABCD'))

In [22]: df
Out[22]: 
                   A         B         C         D
2000-01-01 -0.222193  0.764096 -2.000947 -1.162589
2000-01-02 -0.387643 -0.497687  0.868227 -0.939663
2000-01-03  1.001708 -0.761496  0.179564 -0.403473
2000-01-04  0.469317 -0.161929 -0.844448 -0.211096
2000-01-05  0.580083 -0.952382  0.105044 -0.648209
2000-01-06 -0.312277 -0.762257 -0.894456 -1.169686
2000-01-07 -1.446776 -1.276171 -1.466667  0.800513
2000-01-08 -0.659035 -0.006725 -1.475503  0.353150

In [23]: df.where(df>0, df.A, axis = 1)
Out[23]: 
                   A         B         C         D
2000-01-01       NaN  0.764096       NaN       NaN
2000-01-02       NaN       NaN  0.868227       NaN
2000-01-03  1.001708       NaN  0.179564       NaN
2000-01-04  0.469317       NaN       NaN       NaN
2000-01-05  0.580083       NaN  0.105044       NaN
2000-01-06       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN
2000-01-07       NaN       NaN       NaN  0.800513
2000-01-08       NaN       NaN       NaN  0.353150

In [24]: df.where(df>0, df.A, axis = 0)
Out[24]: 
                   A         B         C         D
2000-01-01 -0.222193  0.764096 -0.222193 -0.222193
2000-01-02 -0.387643 -0.387643  0.868227 -0.387643
2000-01-03  1.001708  1.001708  0.179564  1.001708
2000-01-04  0.469317  0.469317  0.469317  0.469317
2000-01-05  0.580083  0.580083  0.105044  0.580083
2000-01-06 -0.312277 -0.312277 -0.312277 -0.312277
2000-01-07 -1.446776 -1.446776 -1.446776  0.800513
2000-01-08 -0.659035 -0.659035 -0.659035  0.353150
```

I didn't understand the use of `axis` here (frankly speaking I didn't get the concept of alignment.) I know that axis=0 is said to be "column-wise" and axis=1 "row-wise". Could anyone explain me the output (concept of alignment), also the use of `level` parameter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sample for explain:

```
np.random.seed(12)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(8,4), 
                  index = pd.date_range('20000101',periods=8), 
                  columns = list('ABCD'))
print (df)
                   A         B         C         D
2000-01-01  0.472986 -0.681426  0.242439 -1.700736
2000-01-02  0.753143 -1.534721  0.005127 -0.120228
2000-01-03 -0.806982  2.871819 -0.597823  0.472457
2000-01-04  1.095956 -1.215169  1.342356 -0.122150
2000-01-05  1.012515 -0.913869 -1.029530  1.209796
2000-01-06  0.501872  0.138846  0.640761  0.527333
2000-01-07 -1.154360 -2.213333 -1.681757 -1.788094
2000-01-08 -2.218535 -0.647431 -0.528404 -0.039209
```

---

```
#boolean mask by condition
print (df>0)
                A      B      C      D
2000-01-01   True  False   True  False
2000-01-02   True  False   True  False
2000-01-03  False   True  False   True
2000-01-04   True  False   True  False
2000-01-05   True  False  False   True
2000-01-06   True   True   True   True
2000-01-07  False  False  False  False
2000-01-08  False  False  False  False

#without define value for replace False of mask values create NaNs
print (df.where(df>0))
                   A         B         C         D
2000-01-01  0.472986       NaN  0.242439       NaN
2000-01-02  0.753143       NaN  0.005127       NaN
2000-01-03       NaN  2.871819       NaN  0.472457
2000-01-04  1.095956       NaN  1.342356       NaN
2000-01-05  1.012515       NaN       NaN  1.209796
2000-01-06  0.501872  0.138846  0.640761  0.527333
2000-01-07       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN
2000-01-08       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN
```

For replace `False` of mask by some `Series` (row) need `axis=1` - row is repeating ([broadcasting](http://scipy.github.io/old-wiki/pages/EricsBroadcastingDoc)):

```
print (df.loc['2000-01-01'])
A    0.472986
B   -0.681426
C    0.242439
D   -1.700736
Name: 2000-01-01 00:00:00, dtype: float64

print (df.where(df>0, df.loc['2000-01-01'], axis = 1))
                   A         B         C         D
2000-01-01  0.472986 -0.681426  0.242439 -1.700736
2000-01-02  0.753143 -0.681426  0.005127 -1.700736
2000-01-03  0.472986  2.871819  0.242439  0.472457
2000-01-04  1.095956 -0.681426  1.342356 -1.700736
2000-01-05  1.012515 -0.681426  0.242439  1.209796
2000-01-06  0.501872  0.138846  0.640761  0.527333
2000-01-07  0.472986 -0.681426  0.242439 -1.700736
2000-01-08  0.472986 -0.681426  0.242439 -1.700736
```

And for replace by `Series` (column) need `axis=0` - column is repeating ([broadcasting](http://scipy.github.io/old-wiki/pages/EricsBroadcastingDoc))

```
print (df.A)
2000-01-01    0.472986
2000-01-02    0.753143
2000-01-03   -0.806982
2000-01-04    1.095956
2000-01-05    1.012515
2000-01-06    0.501872
2000-01-07   -1.154360
2000-01-08   -2.218535
Freq: D, Name: A, dtype: float64 

print (df.where(df>0, df.A, axis = 0))
                   A         B         C         D
2000-01-01  0.472986  0.472986  0.242439  0.472986
2000-01-02  0.753143  0.753143  0.005127  0.753143
2000-01-03 -0.806982  2.871819 -0.806982  0.472457
2000-01-04  1.095956  1.095956  1.342356  1.095956
2000-01-05  1.012515  1.012515  1.012515  1.209796
2000-01-06  0.501872  0.138846  0.640761  0.527333
2000-01-07 -1.154360 -1.154360 -1.154360 -1.154360
2000-01-08 -2.218535 -2.218535 -2.218535 -2.218535
```

For replace by another `DataFrame`:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(10, size=(8,4)), 
                  index = pd.date_range('20000101',periods=8), 
                  columns = list('ABCD'))
print (df1)
            A  B  C  D
2000-01-01  5  3  5  0
2000-01-02  2  9  6  4
2000-01-03  7  6  2  3
2000-01-04  2  6  4  5
2000-01-05  0  0  5  4
2000-01-06  0  3  7  9
2000-01-07  6  8  6  1
2000-01-08  4  9  6  5

print (df.where(df>0, df1))
                   A         B         C         D
2000-01-01  0.472986  3.000000  0.242439  0.000000
2000-01-02  0.753143  9.000000  0.005127  4.000000
2000-01-03  7.000000  2.871819  2.000000  0.472457
2000-01-04  1.095956  6.000000  1.342356  5.000000
2000-01-05  1.012515  0.000000  5.000000  1.209796
2000-01-06  0.501872  0.138846  0.640761  0.527333
2000-01-07  6.000000  8.000000  6.000000  1.000000
2000-01-08  4.000000  9.000000  6.000000  5.000000
```

EDIT:

Explaining alignment:

Here `where` function is working with 2 objects (Series, DataFrame) and if we come across common columns then common index names data are aligned and function is applied. So here only index `A,B` in `Series` matches with column `A,B` of DataFrame, whereas other columns get NaNs.

```
s = pd.Series(np.random.randint(10, size=4) , index = list('ABEF'))
print (s)
A    5
B    3
E    5
F    0
dtype: int32

print (df.where(df>0, s, axis=1))

                   A         B         C         D
2000-01-01  0.472986  3.000000  0.242439       NaN
2000-01-02  0.753143  3.000000  0.005127       NaN
2000-01-03  5.000000  2.871819       NaN  0.472457
2000-01-04  1.095956  3.000000  1.342356       NaN
2000-01-05  1.012515  3.000000       NaN  1.209796
2000-01-06  0.501872  0.138846  0.640761  0.527333
2000-01-07  5.000000  3.000000       NaN       NaN
2000-01-08  5.000000  3.000000       NaN       NaN
```

EDIT1:

Sample with `level` parameter:

If `DataFrame` has [`MultiIndex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.MultiIndex.html) then it is necessary add parameter `level` for specifying which level of `Multiindex` is to be used for the function `where`.

```
np.random.seed(12)
mux = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([pd.date_range('20000101',periods=8), list('aaaabbbb')],
                                names=('date', 'par'))
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(8,4), 
                  index = mux, 
                  columns = list('ABCD'))
print (df)
                       A         B         C         D
date       par                                        
2000-01-01 a    0.472986 -0.681426  0.242439 -1.700736
2000-01-02 a    0.753143 -1.534721  0.005127 -0.120228
2000-01-03 a   -0.806982  2.871819 -0.597823  0.472457
2000-01-04 a    1.095956 -1.215169  1.342356 -0.122150
2000-01-05 b    1.012515 -0.913869 -1.029530  1.209796
2000-01-06 b    0.501872  0.138846  0.640761  0.527333
2000-01-07 b   -1.154360 -2.213333 -1.681757 -1.788094
2000-01-08 b   -2.218535 -0.647431 -0.528404 -0.039209

s = pd.Series(np.random.randint(10, size=2) , index = list('ac'))
print (s)
a    5
c    3
dtype: int32

print (df.where(df>0, s, axis=0, level=1))
                       A         B         C         D
date       par                                        
2000-01-01 a    0.472986  5.000000  0.242439  5.000000
2000-01-02 a    0.753143  5.000000  0.005127  5.000000
2000-01-03 a    5.000000  2.871819  5.000000  0.472457
2000-01-04 a    1.095956  5.000000  1.342356  5.000000
2000-01-05 b    1.012515       NaN       NaN  1.209796
2000-01-06 b    0.501872  0.138846  0.640761  0.527333
2000-01-07 b         NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN
2000-01-08 b         NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN
```

Comment: What is the use of parameter `level` ?

Comment: In my opinion it is for multiindex in columns or in indexes. Not very often used. Give me some time, I try explain (English is hard for me ;))